# FBConnect/Graph API weird behavior

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So after a long time of debugging here is whats happening. (Using Facebooks Graph API)

When I click my post to facebook button when the facebook app is not installed, the login redirects to safari, logs on, and asks to allow permision for my app, then returns back to my app.. perfect.

If I have the official facebook app installed, the app redirects to the facebook app, and shows no dialog before returning back to my app, with an unknown error.

Basically why is the posting feature not working when authentication goes through the app and not the browser?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GO to Facebook.m file and comment the following lines in the **- (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth** method,

```
       - (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth
                            safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth {
         //some line of code for initial setup

    //Comment these lines
          /*UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
            if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)] && [device isMultitaskingSupported]) {
                if (tryFBAppAuth) {
                    NSString *fbAppUrl = [FBRequest serializeURL:kFBAppAuthURL params:params];
                    didOpenOtherApp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fbAppUrl]];
                }*/
   //code to open the facebook login page

}
```

Why you want do means,Initially it was set to open the Facebook in case of availability of credentials

Comment: This worked so now it wont use the app... But why wont the app work? Seems silly that their code wouldn't work

Comment: @Eric Didnt get wat u r asking?

Comment: Sorry. I guess I am saying thank you, ur suggestion fixed the error. But I am just wondering WHY the code we commented out didnt work in the first place

Comment: @Eric Actually, They are opening the FacebookAPP instead of following with our app.Tat is the problem over here.If its worked for u means, You can accept this

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook ios SDK This will work fine.

In .h file

```
#import "Facebook.h"

Facebook *facebook;
```

In .m file

```
  NSArray * permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 //@"publish_stream",
                                 @"offline_access",
                                 nil];
        [facebook authorize:@"APPID" permissions:permissions delegate:self];



- (void)fbDidLogin {
    //isLoggedIn = YES;
    [self hideActivityLabel];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:facebook.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"exp_date"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"login token:");     
    NSLog(facebook.accessToken);

}

- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {

}
```

Comment: This doesnt work. This is the same code I am already using.. Only works with the safari athentication